# In Microsoft Edge Dev, I have a big error

Tags: microsoft-edge

At 'edge://settings/people' it says 'Not Syncing' and 'To resume sync, sign out and then sign in again'. If I click 'Sign out' I get a warning that says 'When you sign out, this email address will no longer be associated with your profile'. How can I fix this without losing my profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't lose your profile (nothing should change), it just disassociates the e-mail address while you're signed out. It will re-associate when you log back in.